# Yii2 Load schedule using unclead/yii2-multiple-input

Tags: php, yii2

I am using unclead / yii2-multiple-input widget.

I want to generate different number of rows with values from my database.
How can i do this?

I can design my columns in view and edit data manualy after page generated. But miss how to program the number of rows and its values in the view.

My code in view:

```
 <?= $form->field($User, 'User')->widget(MultipleInput::className(), [
        'min' => 0,
        'max' => 4,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'name'  => 'name',
                'title' => 'Name',
                'type' => 'textInput',
                'options' => [
                    'onchange' => $onchange,
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name'  => 'birth',
                'type'  => \kartik\date\DatePicker::className(),
                'title' => 'Birth',
                'value' => function($data) {
                    return $data['day'];
                },

                'options' => [
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                        'todayHighlight' => true
                    ]
                ]
            ],

        ]
        ])->label(false);
```

How can I make (for example) 8 rows with different values, and also have the ability to edit/remove/update some of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into the documentation as it says that you need to assign a separate field into the model which will store all the schedule in form of JSON and then provide it back to the field when editing/updating the model.

You have not added the appropriate model to verify how are you creating the field `User` in your given case above. so, i will try to create a simple example which will help you implement it in your scenario.

For Example.

You have to store a user in the database along with his favorite books.

```
User
id, name, email

Books
id, name
```

- Create a field/column in you `User` table with the name `schedule` of type text, you can write a migration or add manually.
- Add it to the rules in the `User` model as `safe`.

  like below

  ```
  public function rules() {
      return [
          ....//other rules
          [ [ 'schedule'] , 'safe' ]
      ];
  }
  ```
- Add the widget to the newly created column in `ActiveForm`

  see below code

  ```
  echo $form->field($model,'schedule')->widget(MultipleInput::class,[
      'max' => 4,
      'columns' => [
          [
              'name'  => 'book_id',
              'type'  => 'dropDownList',
              'title' => 'Book',
              'items' => ArrayHelper::map( Books::find()->asArray()->all (),'id','name'),
          ],
      ]

  ]);
  ```
- When saving the `User` model convert the array to JSON string.

  like below

  ```
  if( Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ){
      $model->schedule = \yii\helpers\Json::encode($model->schedule);
      $model->save();
  }
  ```
- Override the `afterFind()` of the `User` model to covert the json back to the array before loading the form.

  like below

  ```
  public function afterFind() {
      parent::afterFind();
      $this->schedule = \yii\helpers\Json::decode($this->schedule);
  }
  ```

Now when saved the `schedule` field against the current user will have the JSON for the selected rows for the books, as many selected, for example, if I saved three books having ids(1,2,3) then it will have json like below

```
{
  "0": {
    "book_id": "1"
  },
  "2": {
    "book_id": "2"
  },
  "3": {
    "book_id": "3"
  }
}
```

The above JSON will be converted to an array in the `afterFind()` so that the widget loads the saved schedule when you EDIT the record.

Now go to your update page or edit the newly saved model you will see the books loaded automatically.